# I'm looking for midi software that will allow me to project to my students on both piano and a staff what I am playing

Tags: midi, keyboard, software, education

In my piano class in college, there was an electric piano that had a grand staff built onto it.  Whenever someone played the keyboard, the whole class could see the notes being played light up on the staff.  I want to do that kind of thing with my computer and a midi keyboard so that I can project in real time the notes I am playing on the screen, both on a picture of a keyboard and also on a picture of a grand staff, so that my music classes can have a visual of what they are listening to.  Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for editing to ask for "a way to do this" rather than for specific apps. IMO that ought to have been enough to make it a valid question. Unfortunately, the best and easiest answer is "Sure; find an app that does that!" Googling "display piano keys on screen" mentions 4 or 5 in the first few results. Seems like something called "Chordie" is popular (confusingly, "chordie.com" is an unrelated site full of tabs). More complicated ways could involve screen-sharing while recording in a DAW or music-notation program.